# Bat script start a program and than restart

Tags: batch-file, batch

I need some help creating a .bat script that starts a program and when done it restarts the computer.

```
cmd /c C:\"Program Files"\"Toolwiz Time Freeze"\ToolwizTimeFreeze.exe /usepass=password /freezealways
```

This is what is should do first. This works fine. This will enable the program to protect after every restart. That's why I need to add a restart. I was thinking of adding this

```
&& shutdown /r /f /0
```

Problem is that the command prompt keeps hanging. And the shutdown does not go through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you should use for the shutdown command is:

shutdown -r -f -t 0

I think it might be your /0 that is throwing it off. The full syntax can be found here on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you launch another instance of `cmd`? Simply use

```
C:\"Program Files"\"Toolwiz Time Freeze"\ToolwizTimeFreeze.exe /usepass=password /freezealways
shutdown /r /f /0
```

or, if shutdown should depend on previous command [exit code](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html):

```
C:\"Program Files"\"Toolwiz Time Freeze"\ToolwizTimeFreeze.exe /usepass=password /freezealways
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    shutdown /r /f /0
) else (
    echo No success, an error occurred
    rem add next commands here (optional)
)
```

Comment: Yeah the cmd shouldn't have been there. I just pasted my command here. I will test out your suggestion. Thanks a lot for the effort